# Indexing Mysql Database with elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I recently started looking ElasticSearch to implement search in my
application. I have my database in Mysql which have approx. >2 mn
records. I know in sphinx we could create an index directly on any
mysql table column. I wanted to know if its possible in Elasticsearch,
if not directly how we could implement that?

Thanks
Mohit

Answer (score 4):

There is no native support (at this time) for mysql in Elastic Search like there is in Sphinx.

Elastic Search is a great option for search, but you'll have probably to do some custom work to trigger reindexing of items when they change in your database.  Exactly how that is accomplished will depend alot on your application.  Elastic Search has great near real time search functionality, and has been proven to [perform well under heavy indexing load](http://engineering.socialcast.com/2011/05/realtime-search-solr-vs-elasticsearch/) so triggering reindexing shouldn't a concern for most applications.

The [NoSQL movement](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2010/02/25/nosql_yessearch.html) seems to gaining steam as well.  [Some applications](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/jetslide-uses-elasticsearch-as-database/) use Elastic Search as the only data store.

Comment: @catalinux (below) is correct, github project he mentioned allows moving of tables from mySQL to elasticSearch

Comment: @coderman - the OP is asking about native support,  like Sphinx. River JDBC is a poller that is a very useful for replication,  but it's not native support.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc does that. You can syncronize data from mysql source, using an "operations table".

It,s a little bit tricky first time installing, but it works.

First you have to install the plugin
Second, you have to set up ( configure) the imported data

Answer (score 0):

- What is Logstash? Logstash is a data collection engine with real-time
  pipelining capabilities. You can use Logstash to collect your logs,
  parse them into your desirable format and store them for searching or
  monitoring for your application.

**Step-1**: Download latest version of
   elastic search

**Step-2:** After downloading logstasch need to install jdbc plugin

bin/plugin install logstash-input-jdbc

**Step-3:** Download mysql-jdbc driver...as i downloaded and the file
   name is mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar. put this file inside
   logstash/drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar ....you can put it
   anywhere you want. but remember the path.

**Step-4:** Now create a db.conf file and put it inside logstash
   directory...in my case logstash-2.3.2/logstash-jdbc.conf here is the
   content:

### input { jdbc { jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/logstash-2.3.2/drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar" jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myapp_development" jdbc_user => "root" jdbc_password => "admin" parameters => { "user_list" => "users" } schedule => "* * * * *" statement => "select name,email from users" } } output { elasticsearch { index => "users" document_type => "users" document_id => "%{123}" hosts => "localhost:9200" } }

Jdbc Input Parameter Description

jdbc_driver_library  Full path of jdbc library  jdbc_driver_class    JDBC
   driver class to load, for MySQL it is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
   jdbc_connection_string   JDBC mysql connection string  jdbc_user MySQL
   user  jdbc_password  MySQL user password  schedule   Run input statement
   every minutes. Available scheduling option  statement    MySQL statement
   parameters   Parameter to pass in MySQL statement

Jdbc Output Parameters Description

Parameter   Description
index   Elasticsearch Index name 
   document_type    Elasticsearch Index type.
  document_id       Id of elastic search doc

---

**Step-5:** Now set up is complete. we need to start logstart. before that start elasicsearch

then start logstsh and give it jadbc-db.conf file for configuration $
   cd logstash-2.3.2 $ bin/logstash agent -f logstash-jdbc.conf

Now test your data quick in elastic search
   http://localhost:9200/users/users/_search

Thank You Debs

Comment: Don't go for downloading river and all.it will create headache. Use Logstash to input data into elastic search. This will help you definitely.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options in this case:-

1. Event based , so you can trigger an event on api level and listen to the event to re-sync the changes.
2. Orm Level, most of the Orms have hooks, so you can listen to the hooks and re-sync Elastic search.